# Rails uses different default url options in views vs controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Scratching my head over this.

Recently opened a new reverse proxy to our site via nginx to support a new domain.  When you access via either old.server.com or new.server.com you hit our backend.

If you hit via old.server.com, all the url helpers work fine and produce valid absolute URLs.  But if you hit via new.server.com (the new reverse proxy host) then url helpers only work correctly in views.  URL helpers used in the controllers use the hostname plus the actual unicorn port -- which is incorrect for URLs we want to send out.

Even more confusing, this is only the case in the controllers.  In the views, this works correctly in all cases.  In order to make this work in controllers when using the new.server.com  I need to override the default_url_options method in the ApplicationController.

Yes, I have both the `Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host]` and `Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:protocol]` configurations setup correctly.

I feel like I probably missed forwarding some required header in the reverse proxy, but haven't figured it out.  But more importantly, why are the views and controllers using different contexts for generating absolute URLs?

UPDATE:

The difference between the two hosts appeared to be the value being provided by the reverse proxy for the Host header.  The "old" proxy was sending the public host for it, and the "new" proxy was sending nothing.  Rails appears to use the Host header in constructing URLs in the absence of explicit data.  In order to fix this I either need to set the Host header correctly or implement the `default_url_options` method in my controller.

So, I now have working code, but it seems like a Really Bad Idea(TM) that controllers and views are not using the exact same code/setup for creating URLs.  Is this just standard rails, or did I miss some configuration?